# Динамическая подгрузка данных VK API

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, android-asynctask

Реализую динамическую подгрузку классическим алгоритмом: в методе типа AsyncTask генерирую новые записи и отрисовываю продолжение списка. Сама задача вызывается в интерфейсе onScrollListener при достижении конца текущего списка.

Проблема заключается в том, что первый запрос к VK API не срабатывает, в логах onError. После открытия и закрытия боковой панели меню NavigationDrawer запрос срабатывает. При скроллинге сначала трижды подгружаются 20 одних и тех же последних записей, а после подгрузка работает, как нужно. 
Подскажите, где заблуждаюсь?

Фрагмент кода:

```
private class LoadMoreAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<WallPost>> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        @Override
        protected List<WallPost> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                List<WallPost> data = generate(listOffset, 20);
                listOffset = listOffset + 20;
                return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LoadMoreAsyncTask", "Loading data", e);
            }
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<WallPost> data) {
            if (data.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.error_loading_items), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            postsAdapter.add(data);
            postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int index = postView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int top = (postView.getChildAt(0) == null) ? 0 : postView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
            postView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        }
    }

    /*
     *      Метод выборки очередных постов для подгрузки
     */
    public List<WallPost> generate(int startIndex, int count) {
        List<WallPost> l = new ArrayList<WallPost>(count);
        if (VKSdk.wakeUpSession()) {
           startLoading();
        }
        for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex+count; i++) {
            l.add(wallPosts.get(i));
        }
        return l;
    }
```

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;

        if(loadMore && loadingTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            loadingTask = new LoadMoreAsyncTask();
            loadingTask.execute(totalItemCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А скроллистинер где?

Comment: добавил в текст вопроса

Comment: где вы создаете `listOffset` ? и какая первое значение?

Comment: описываю глобально, там же сразу зануляю. по ссылке на дропбокс можно посмотреть полный код файла MainActivity.java https://www.dropbox.com/s/w627ggm2xptxwfn/MainActivity.java?dl=0